sed: copy lines up to and including match, and then add a newline
I have this sed expression:
sed -ne '1,/DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN/p' filename.txt

This outputs every line up to and include the line that contains DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN.
How do I modify this command so that it appends a newline after the DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN?
Example:
hello
there
DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN
not
this
DO-NOT-TOUCH-END
extra
lines

becomes:
hello
there
DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN


There is a blank line after DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN
I also want something similar for the other side, where it prepends a newline before the match.
sed -ne '/DO-NOT-TOUCH-END/,$p' filename.txt

So the output should be:

DO-NOT-TOUCH-END
extra
lines

There is a blank line before DO-NOT-TOUCH-END.

sed -ne '1,/DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN/p;$a\\' filename.txt

That adds two newlines.

sorry I was just to late to remove the n...  It should be: sed -ne '1,/DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN/p;$a\\' filename.txt

a:  Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash. (from man sed )

Thanks, that worked.    How about the second question?  How do I prepend a newline?

What about: sed -ne '/DO-NOT-TOUCH-END/,$p;1i\\'  filename.txt ?

is that all the script will do, or is this part of a longer script? If the former you could do. for example: sed '/DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN/!b;G;q' file

it also makes a difference if DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN and DO-NOT-TOUCH-END can appear more than once, and in what order. and if empty line should still be printed if BEGIN/END lines do not appear

alternatives: (sed -n '1,/begin/p' file; echo) / (echo; sed -n '/end/,$p' file)

Thanks everyone, I've decided to go with Luuk's answers.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed '/DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN/G' file

Append the hold space to the current matched line, which by default will be empty but will append a newline.
For before operation:
sed '/DO-NOT-TOUCH-END/H;//g' file

Append the current line to the hold space and then replace the current line by the contents of the hold space.
Alternatively:
sed 's/DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN/&\n/;s/DO-NOT-TOUCH-END/\n&/' file


Just use awk for clarity, simplicity, flexibility, efficiency, etc.:
To append a newline:
$ awk '1; /DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN/{print ""; exit}' file
hello
there
DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN


To prepend a newline:
$ awk '/DO-NOT-TOUCH-END/{print ""; f=1} f' file

DO-NOT-TOUCH-END
extra
lines

To do both:
$ awk '/DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN/{$0=$0 ORS} /DO-NOT-TOUCH-END/{$0=ORS $0} 1' file
hello
there
DO-NOT-TOUCH-BEGIN

not
this

DO-NOT-TOUCH-END
extra
lines

awk is made up of condition { action } blocks with the default condition being "true" and the default action "print the current record" so in the first script above 1 is a true condition in that context and so the current record is printed. That script also exits once the regexp matches so awk doesn't waste time reading the rest of the input and discarding it.
In the second script f is set to 1 (true) when the regexp matches and is 0-or-null (false) before it so, courtesy of the test of f as a condition at the end, records only get printed starting from when the regexp matches.
In the third script we aren't starting or stopping printing, just adding a newline (as stored in the variable ORS to be whatever means "newline" on your platform, e.g. a LineFeed in Unix) to the output wherever appropriate.
